# Prove $X^2\perp Y^2$

Tags: probability

Prove that if $X$ and $Y$ are non-negative independent random variables, then $X^2\perp Y^2$.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using $\perp$ for independence. (Orthogonality in $L^{2}$ is obviously false). If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are independent for any two measurable functions $f$ and $g$: $$P(f(X) \in A, g(Y) \in B)=P(X \in f^{-1} (A)), Y \in g^{-1}(B ))$$ $$=P(X \in f^{-1} (A))P(Y \in g^{-1} (B))=P(f(X) \in A) P(g(Y) \in B).$$ Take $f(x)=g(x)=x^{2}$.